# Convergence in the sense of distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

I'm having some trouble with a seemingly simple exercise. I usually know how to verify convergence in the sense of distributions, but this time I'm looking at something a little different. I need to find a distribution $T$ so that $T'\rightarrow 2\delta_1$ in D'(R).

My attempt is the following: using the property of test functions I consider: $$<T',\phi>=-<T,\phi '>=-\int_a^bT\phi 'dx=-T\phi|_a^b+\int_a^bT'\phi dx$$

but the last integral is $<T',\phi>$, so I did this (which I'm not sure is allowed...) $$<T',\phi>=-T\phi|_a^b+<T',\phi> \rightarrow -T\phi|_a^b=0=2\phi(1) \rightarrow T(a)\phi(a)-T(b)\phi(b)=2\phi(1)$$

And now I just arbitrarily decided to consider $a=1 , b=\infty , T(1)=2$ so that I get $$T=2I_{[1,\infty)}$$

where $I_{[1,\infty)}$ is the indicator function of the subset $[1,\infty)$

Proof:

$$<T',\phi>=-<T,\phi '>=-2\int_1^\infty\phi 'dx=-2\[\phi(x)]_1^\infty=-2[-\phi(1)]=2\phi(1)=2\delta_1$$
where $\phi(\infty)=0$ due to test functions being compactly supported.

I'm pretty sure the answer is correct, but the method isn't. I'm not sure how else to tackle this.
Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure whether I can follow the first step. How can you write the evaluation of $T$ at $\phi'$ as an integral? Is this an assumption you are making? Moreover I am not sure I see where you need convergence? Are you simply looking for a distribution whose derivative is the $2\delta_1$?

Comment: Ok so I might be using the wrong terms because I'm translating, I'm sorry for that. But since the question is to determine a distribution whose derivative converges to $2\delta_1$ in $D'(R)$, I tried to "make" it converge. As far as I know, to determine che convergence of a distribution you feed a test function to it, and $$<T,\phi>=\int_RT(x)\phi (x)dx$$ is just a definition. The transfer of the derivative and the appearence of the minus is a consequence of test functions having boundary conditions null (not sure if it's the right term, sorry again). 
I hope this clears things up. Thank you